# Why php process wait another one?

Tags: php, nginx, plesk, fpm

This days, my server has a problem.

2 different PHP process can't run one time.

Let's say if I has a PHP process running within 30 seconds.

I want to run another PHP process at the same time while first process still running and not yet done.
But the 2nd process can't run right away, it will wait for the first process done then it run after that.

This doesn't happen earlier.

How to fix that?

Example php files:

*file1.php*:

```
sleep(30); exit('done);
```

*file2.php*:

```
exit('done');
```

My server use plesk, php 7.x PHP-FPM Nginx

Comment: how do you ensure that the both processes are not running simultaneously ?

Comment: i wrongly suggested to stackoverflow that this question is okay, but it requires editing, please update the question answering my previous question in comment @Thinh Phan

Comment: @RatulSharker I run 2 file in chrome browser, and see the 2nd file pending until the first file complete.

Comment: update the question according to your finding.

Comment: Have a look on PHP `pcntl_fork()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

Comment: Guess this is not all the code and your using session?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone you are right, I used session_start() in both file. When I comment one of them, then  2 file can run at the same time without wait other. Can you explain me why?

Comment: Because the session is locking, you can still use a session if you need it, just close it with [`session_write_close();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php). Some details about why it does it on that page.

Comment: Check the duplicate, my answer over there as a more in-depth explanation of why this happens.

Comment: @CBroe, I read yoru answer, and yep, that's reason in my case too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is the cause of my problem.

I used session_start() in both file, and when the first one running, the season locked, the 2nd file must wait until the locked release.

Thanks @LawrenceCherone for your answer